# ASP.NET MVC 5 Button Event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to add some functionality to a button I made using the following html code:

```
    <div>
        <p style="display: inline">
            Strength:&thinsp; <b>@str</b>
        </p>
    </div>
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Add Strength" onclick="addValue('str');"/>
```

When I click this button, I want to change a value I stored with Razor;

```
@{
    int str = 5;
}
```

I've Googled a bit, read the documentation but I can't find anything, which works.
I made a javascript function which I called on onclick, but when I was debugging the code didn't get inside the scope of said function.
Here's the function:

```
function addValue(kind) {
    if (ran == 0) { initialize(); }
    if (left != 0) {
        left--;
        if (kind == "str") {
            str++;
        } else if (kind == "dex") {
            dex++;
        } else if (kind == "intl") {
            intl++;
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can explain to me how I can get some kind of function on my button I'd appreciate it.

Comment: pls add your javascript function

Comment: you can do it with jquery since there is no server side required here unless u want to get the value from database

Comment: You cant increment variables stored in Razor/C# using Javascript - Unless you call your backend.

Comment: Added javascript function, @Valkyriee how would I go about doing this with jQuery?

Comment: It is important to understand how ASP.NET MVC works to better grasp your question here. A browser sends an HTTP request to the server. This request is intercepted by the runtime, and some controller action executes eventually returning HTML to the client browser. Once reached the client browser, there's no longer any notion of Razor or server variables or any ASP.NET MVC. Everything is gone. All that's left is some HTML DOM and javascript code running on the client. So asking how to modify a Razor variable using javascript code from a client browser is like asking how to resurrect a dead man.

Comment: That being said, you can use javascript to make an asynchronous HTTP request back to the server (concept more commonly known as AJAX) which would allow your server to once again execute controller actions and act upon some server side variables. Unfortunately from the context you provided in your question it is pretty hard to be able to give some directions.

Comment: So how would I go about storing an int somewhere and incrementing it when I press a button?

Comment: Please define *somewhere*. Server side? Client side? If it is server side, do you want to persist this information across more than one request?
 Like storing it in some persistent storage such as a database or something? Please be very precise when asking questions. Programming is a precise science.

Comment: Server side. I do need to use it afterwards, so that seems the most useful

Comment: Why do you think that it is most useful? For example you could use cookies which would allow you to store information that could be reused between multiple server side requests and be accessible from both the client and the server. Unfortunately you haven't provided any details about whether this information should be shared between the users of your website or should it be specific only to the current user. Is it session specific? Too much details are lacking from your question.

Comment: Mostly because I only use it to later store it in my database

Comment: Then why not directly store this variable in the database and access it from there on subsequent requests?

Comment: Because I have no idea how I would go about that. I'm already having a hard time figuring out how to add an event to a button, so I haven't really looked at any ways to store data in my database via ASP yet.

Comment: Accessing a SQL database in .NET is unrelated to ASP.NET MVC. You could access a SQL database the same way from a desktop application as you would from a web application. The underlying layer in .NET is called ADO.NET (google it). It allows you to execute SQL queries against a relational database. I suggest you reading about it from an application agnostic perspective (ASP.NET MVC, WinForms, WPF, ... it's all the same). If you want an object relational mapper on top of native SQL you might consider Entity Framework. Once again, a technology completely agnostic from ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Yeah, I already have a database set up and I have access to it and everything outside my ASP project. I just didn't check how I would go about it

Comment: So my point here is that there are different layers in .NET (like sub-frameworks) that you might consider reading about. Each of them is responsible for specific things: accessing files and streams (System.IO), TCP, UDP, HTTP (System.Net), accessing a relational database (System.Data), REST services (ASP.NET Web API), web applications (ASp.NET MVC and WebForms), ... You can learn each of those parts independently of the others.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have stored the variable within this div tag(which can be anything else):

```
<div id="divValue">@str</div>
```

And this is your button:

```
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Add Strength" id="btn"/>
```

Using jquery:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btn').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var textValue = $('#divValue').text();

                if (textValue == "str") {
                    $('#divValue').text('changeText'); 
                    //or other action
                } else if (textValue == "dex") {
                    //action
                } else if (textValue == "intl") {
                    //action
                    }

            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try it out in a bit

Answer (score 0):

use hidden input field in razor to store value in html

```
@Html.Hidden("str",str,new {@id = "str"})
```

and use following javascript to retrieve and store value in str hidden field

```
$("#str").val("value you want to store");

var value = $("#str").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to make sure that your button go with the javascript function as you have 
you will have your page refreshed without knowing what happen so you need to prevent this behavior with

```
e.preventDefault();
```

in your javascript function or just change the input type to button

```
<input type='button' .../>
```

the second thing you have to notice that to change c# variable value you need some server side processing so you can use ajax.

if it's just some small thing can be done with your client side so you can add your variable to a hidden field and manupilate it with javascrip / jquery like this

```
<input type='hidden' id='myhiddenvar' value='@myvar'/>
```

and with jquery handle it like

```
var $myvar=$("#myhiddenvar").val();//get Value From Hidden Field
$myvar++;
$("#myhiddenvar").val(myvar);//Put Back To Hidden field
```